# Combining Arrays and Summing Integers

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm working with multiple Arrays each with one string and many integers. I have managed to set together duplicates in nested arrays as I want to combine them. So as I loop over my parent array it outputs this:

```
[["word", 1, 1, 3, 4], ["word", 2, 1, 3, 4]]
```

and another example:

```
[["without", 1, 1, 3, 4], ["without", 2, 1, 3, 4], ["without", 3, 1, 0, 0]]
```

I want a function to combine these into one array and sum the integers. So the first example above would become:

```
["word", 3, 2, 6, 8]
```

I have tried many different techniques like inject and reduce. My latest attempt isn't the most elegant:

```
# data is set of array
def inject_array(data)
  clicks = 0
  imps = 0
  cost = 0 
  converted_clicks = 0
  data.each do |i|
    clicks += i[1]
    i[1] = clicks
    imps += i[2]
    i[2] = imps
    cost += i[3]
    i[3] = cost
    converted_clicks += i[4]
    i[4] = converted_clicks
  end
```

It's getting a bit messy, is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but wouldn't it be better to keep track of the sum using a hash?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the arrays will always be the same length, you can use `Array#transpose` to transpose your array of arrays from row-based to column-based arrays:

```
[["word", 1, 1, 3, 4], ["word", 2, 1, 3, 4]].transpose
 => [["word", "word"], [1, 2], [1, 1], [3, 3], [4, 4]]
```

From there, it's trivial enough to sum the numbers in each:

```
[["word", 1, 1, 3, 4], ["word", 2, 1, 3, 4]].transpose.map.with_index do |e, i|
  i == 0 ? e.first : e.inject(:+)
end # => ["word", 3, 2, 6, 8]
```

Comment: I much prefer this way than my own brute force rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

You can also methods of the class [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html). Recall that to sum each column of a matrix with `r` rows, you pre-multiply the matrix by a row vector comprised of `r` `1`s:

```
require 'matrix'

a = [["word", 1, 1, 3, 4], ["word", 2, 1, 3, 4]]

[a.first.first, (Matrix[[1]*a.size] * Matrix[*a.map { |e| e[1..-1] }]).to_a.first]
   #=> ["word", [3, 2, 6, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to loop over the arrays, sum the parts, and rebuild.

```
word_array = [['word', 1, 1, 3, 4], ['word', 2, 1, 3, 4]]
puts "Squashing #{word_array}..."
i1 = 0
i2 = 0
i3 = 0
i4 = 0
word_array.each do |arr|
  i1 += arr[1]
  i2 += arr[2]
  i3 += arr[3]
  i4 += arr[4]
end
puts ['word', i1, i2, i3, i4].inspect
```